# Random Forest- change in model performance due to same values in one of the independent

Tags: regression, machine-learning

What will happen in random forest if one of the independent variable has no change in value (have same answer) for all the samples?

Answer (score 3):

Then by definition it carries no information whatsoever, and should be dropped from the model building *a priori*.

Answer (score 2):

The variable will not end up being used, as it will not be possible to split the samples based on this variable. The only case where it may end up being used is if you subsample your features in such a way, that the model has to split on a single variable at some point.